# Can somebody abuse my hardware's id's?

Tags: hardware

I know that game companies ban cheaters' hardware IDs so they wouldn't be able to play on their server anymore.

I also know that there are programs used so the client system sends a randomly made-up hardware id to the server. (like Virtualbox)

So I've come to the conclusion that IT IS POSSIBLE that some hacker, for example, can steal my hardware id and then cheat in a game I love to play so MY HARDWARE ID would be banned.

So what's the deal? should I protect my hardware id like my public IP then?
If so, how to not leak them outside my PC?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 21.04 and using Virtualbox to emulate another Ubuntu and a Windows.

Comment: Please explain what a hardware ID is and where it comes from.

Comment: @user For example CPU has a physical id pinned to it which does not change , same as GPU,SSD,HDD,etc... You New?

Comment: Are you referring to the MAC ID? It's kinda known that you can spoof MAC ID's AND IP's. If that's what you're asking, yeah, you can spoof the machine ID.

Comment: But you've also talked about the IP. That's something very different. Are you sure that game servers track things like CPU id? How would a hacker get the CPU id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There is no one Hardware ID

Let's make a quick thought experiment. Say, you change your computer's RAM, from 2x4GB to 2x8GB. Is it still the same computer?

What if you changed the graphics card? Or the SSD? Or the motherboard? When does it stop being your computer? [And what if you took the replaced components and built a new computer out of it?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)

So to summarize, there is not one "Hardware ID", but every component may have its own ID.

### Are these set in stone?

No, they are not! Your hardware exposes some ID through a driver to the OS, and the OS can then choose to expose that to a userspace program, if it chooses to do so. As you may have guessed, there are plenty of ways to spoof this.

So if a game reads that the serial number of your SSD is `DHX0B3331`, that may or may not correspond to an ID that is burned into the SSD itself. It may be a value provided by the user through a modified driver, or the value may be hardcoded into the driver. There is no way for the game to tell.

### Are Hardware ID bans effective?

Yes and no. As you just saw, a cheater can change their hardware IDs with relative ease. Of course, a game can require administrative privileges for some anti-cheat system, which would then implement its own driver for the hardware, which would in turn then query the real hardware ID, but at this point, many players would be up in arms, questioning why they as fair players should tolerate some random company having administrative access to their computer.

Furthermore, it deters "low-effort cheaters", which won't go as far as to modify their own hardware drivers, solely so they could cheat in some videogame. But to the determined cheater, this is likely not an issue.

## What can a hacker do with my serial numbers?

As you described, a hacker could get your hardware ID banned. There isn't much you can do against that, except to appeal with customer support, stating that the IP from which the offending player connected isn't associated with any location you usually play from, which in turn would make it very likely your ban would get removed.

However, it should also be noted that many games use *account-level bans* instead of *hardware-level bans*. While this does not deter cheaters who's goal it is to ruin other people's fun, it is quite effective against cheaters who try to use illicit means to further their account's progress.

## How can I protect myself?

You can't, really. You used your "local IP" as an example, and it's a pretty bad one. My local IP is `192.168.1.2` and I'm certain that that's also the case for at least one other person reading this answer.

As explained above, "hardware-level bans" aren't really a thing anymore, as they're rather impractical. And griefing hackers usually don't care about getting your account banned, as they can't witness your reaction to it. These people are doing this so they can get a reaction out of other players.

In essence: **Don't worry!**

Comment: *stating that the IP from which the offending player connected isn't associated with any location you usually play from, which in turn would make it very likely your ban would get removed* - so you're allowed to cheat once in a while, as long as you do it over a VPN?

Comment: @nobody Well if that player is a good tidy one while he is in japan , and once in a blue moon decides to cheat with his network why wouldn't the game company buy that it wasn't him,..

Comment: Anti-cheat programs are _commonly_ kernel-level now, and of course are installed with admin privileges, so fair players already tolerate such drivers.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Allowing Kernel-level access to a piece of software you don't control is the biggest vulnerability you can introduce to any system. I would only do that on a VM dedicated to that specific game/app.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Depends on the specific anti-cheat software in question.